# Examples of multiplier Hopf algebras

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, examples, hopf-algebras

A multiplier Hopf-algebra (introduced by Van Daele) is a pair $(A, \Delta)$ where $A$ is a  non-degenerate algebra $A$ together with a non-degenerate algebra morphism $\Delta: A \to M(A \otimes A)$ such that

(i) the following subsets of $M(A \otimes A)$ are contained in $A \otimes A$:

$$\Delta(A)(1 \otimes A), \quad \Delta(A)(A \otimes 1), \quad (A \otimes 1) \Delta(A), \quad (1 \otimes A)\Delta(A).$$

(ii) $\Delta$ is coassociative.

(iii) The following maps $A \otimes A \to A \otimes A$ are bijective:
$$a \otimes b \mapsto(a \otimes 1)\Delta(b), \quad a \otimes b \mapsto \Delta(a)(1  \otimes b)$$

Examples include:

- Any Hopf-algebra.
- The finitely supported functions on a group $X$. Here, the comultiplication is given by
  $$\Delta(f)(x,y) = f(xy)$$

Are there any easy other examples?

Comment: What is $M(A\otimes A)$ ? And what does non-degenerate mean here ?